# State updates but Table doesn't re-render/update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using django channels to update my React table. The channels work perfectly and sends update to react. With the received update, I update the react state but the table doesn't update or re-render to display added data.

I have console logged the data gotten from the channels and the React state, it updates perfectly, I have also tried using react lifecycles like shouldcomponentupdate and componentdidupdate, yet the state is updating perfectly but the table isn't

This is how I updated the state:

```
addMessage(message) {
  console.log("message")
  this.setState({
    data: [...this.state.data, message]
  })
}
setMessages(messages) {
  console.log(messages)
  this.setState({ data: messages })
}
```

And this is a summary of how the table looks

```
render(){
  const {data} = this.state
  console.log(data) //shows updated data at every update
  return(
    <table>
      {data.map(n => {
        return(
          <tr key={n.id}>
             <td> {n.name} </td>
             <td> {n.found} </td>
             <td> {n.date} </td>
          </tr>
      )})}

</table>
)}
```

This is the full component as requestd(it's too long that was why I minimized it)

```
class EnhancedTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      order: 'asc',
      orderBy: 'calories',
      selected: [],
      data:[],
      message: [],
      messages: [],
      page: 0,
      rowsPerPage: 50,
      expanded: false,
      search:''
    };
    this.waitForSocketConnection(() => {
      WebSocketInstance.addCallbacks(this.setMessages.bind(this), this.addMessage.bind(this));
      WebSocketInstance.newChatMessage(this.props.message)
      WebSocketInstance.fetchMessages()

    })

  }



waitForSocketConnection(callback) {
  const component = this;
  setTimeout(
    function () {
      if (WebSocketInstance.state() === 1) {
        console.log('connection is secure');

        callback()

        return;
      } else {
        console.log('waiting for connection')
        component.waitForSocketConnection(callback)
      }
    }, 100);
}

addMessage(message) {
  console.log("message")
  let newData = [...this.state.data, message]
  this.setState({

    data: newData
  })
}
setMessages(messages) {
  console.log(messages)
  this.setState({ data: messages })
}

componentDidMount() {
  WebSocketInstance.connect()
}


  handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const orderBy = property;
    let order = 'desc';

    if (this.state.orderBy === property && this.state.order === 'desc') {
      order = 'asc';
    }

    this.setState({ order, orderBy });
  };

  handleSelectAllClick = event => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.setState(state => ({ selected: state.data.map(n => n.id) }))
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ selected: [] });
  };

  handleAddClick = () => event => {
    const selected = this.state.selected
    selected.forEach(function (element) {
      axios.put(`${process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_API_URL}/api/main/${element}/`, {
        relevance: true
      })
        .then((response) =>
          console.log(response)
        )
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        })

    }
    )

  }

  handleClick = (event, id) => {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(id);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
      );
    }

    this.setState({ selected: newSelected });
  };

  handleChangePage = (event, page) => {
    this.setState({ page });
  };

  handleChangeRowsPerPage = event => {
    this.setState({ rowsPerPage: event.target.value });
  };

  handleChange = panel => (event, expanded) => {
    this.setState({
      expanded: expanded ? panel : false,
    });
  };


  isSelected = id => this.state.selected.indexOf(id) !== -1;

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { order, orderBy, selected, rowsPerPage, page, data, expanded } = this.state;
    const emptyRows = rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, data.length - page * rowsPerPage);
    // const { expanded } = this.state;
   console.log(data)
    return (
      <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected.length} handleAddClick={this.handleAddClick()} />
        <div className={classes.tableWrapper}>
          <Table className={classes.table} aria-labelledby="tableTitle">
            <EnhancedTableHead
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={this.handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={this.handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={data.length}
            />
            <TableBody>

              {stableSort(data, getSorting(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map(n => {
                  const isSelected = this.isSelected(n.id);
                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover

                      key={n.id}

                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox" onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n.id)}
                        role="checkbox"
                        aria-checked={isSelected}
                        tabIndex={-1}
                        key={n.id}
                        selected={isSelected}>
                        <Checkbox checked={n.relevance === true ? true : false} classes={{
                          root: classes.root,

                        }} />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none" style={{ color: "#1565C0" }}>
                        <a href={`${n.url}`} target="_blank" rel='noopener noreferrer'>{expanded === false ? `${n.url.slice(0, 30)}` : `${n.url}`}</a>

                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">{n.keyword}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none"><ExpansionPanel
                        square
                        expanded={expanded === `${n.id}`}
                        onChange={this.handleChange(`${n.id}`)}
                      >
                        <ExpansionPanelSummary>
                          <Typography style={{ color: `${n.keyword ? 'red' : 'none'}` }}>{n.source.slice(1, 100)}...</Typography> <Button color="primary" style={{ padding: '0px' }}>{expanded === false ? 'Read More' : 'Read Less'}</Button>
                        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                          <div>
                            {n.source.split(',').map(element => {
                              return (<Typography key={Math.random()} >{element.replace(n.keyword, n.keyword.toUpperCase())}</Typography>)
                            })}

                          </div>


                        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                      </ExpansionPanel>

                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.found}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">
                        {n.severityLevel === 'low' ?
                          <Badge className={classes.margin} badgeContent={"Low"} color="primary">
                            <CloudCircle />
                          </Badge>
                          :
                          <Badge className={classes.margin} badgeContent={"High"} color="secondary">
                            <AddCircleIcon />
                          </Badge>}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right" style={{ color: "#2E7D32" }}>{n.timestamp}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow style={{ height: 49 * emptyRows }}>
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </div>
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={data.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          backIconButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'Previous Page',
          }}
          nextIconButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'Next Page',
          }}
          onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

EnhancedTable.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(EnhancedTable);
```

I expected as the state updates, the table updates and shows updated data.

Comment: Can you show the code inside `return` as well, so we can try to help you think along in the problem?

Comment: @Karamell I have edited to display the table content

Comment: It would be better if you will show us the full code of the component. I bet you did not initialized the `state` object.

Comment: I have pasted the full code, I felt it was too long so I went straight to the point by summarizing it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this using redux and react lifecycle method,

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
if (this.state.data !== nextState.data){
  this.setState({
    data: nextState.data
  })
  return true
}
return false
```

}

This compares the current state and the next state.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `key` prop on your loops children? When you make loops in your render function you need to provide the `key` prop to the loops child so React knows what components to update.
So in your case it would be something like this: `{data.map(n => <Component key={n.id} />)}` if `n` is an object with an **unique** property `id`.

React key prop: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Yes I am using key prop

Comment: Key prop does not matter in this case, because it affects only the `ReactNode` update, not initialization. I mean, if the array length stay the same and it is being updated, then there will be no changes applied (probably, because keyless array render is inconsistent). If the lengh of the array is being changed, there is a 100% guarantee, that all elements will be displayed even without any key prop.